# Powershell string not recognized as valid DateTime

Tags: powershell

I got a code to convert Date as below:

```
$DatePart = get-aduser -identity $AcountName -Properties * | Select-Object whenCreated
$DatePartSubs =$DatePart.whenCreated
$DatePartSubstring = $DatePartSubs.ToShortDateString()
$FinalDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($DatePartSubstring,'dd/MM/yyyy',$null)
```

But when i tried to format date i got below error

[image]

Where variable "$DatePartSubstring" equals :

[image]

What i did wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: `DatePartSubs` itself is `datetime` object right?

Comment: yes, it is, so i th9n i can use it

Comment: I wonder if its an international issue.  What is your current culture?  You can see that by doing a get-host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out it converts the date to the required format:

```
[datetime]$DatePartSubstring = "2019-06-13"
$FinalDate = $DatePartSubstring.ToString("dd/mm/yyy")
Write-Host $FinalDate -ForegroundColor Green
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to get the date part, without the time, as a date-time object, where the time has been set to midnight.  Converting to a sting and back again is the long way around.  You might be better off to do the following:

```
$DatePart = get-aduser -identity $AcountName -Properties * | Select-Object whenCreated
$FinalDate = $DatePart.whencreated.Date
```

This should set final date to midnight of the day in question.  Note, however, that if you attempt to display $FinalDate on the console,  Powershell will implicitly convert it to a string before displaying it.  In order to find out what it really is, do

```
$FinalDate.GetType()
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell conveniently maps quite a lot of LDAP attributes to more friendly names **and** on some of the attributes it converts them to more usable object types.
Especially on attributes that we would like to use as DateTime objects and that are stored in AD as [Generalized-Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/s-string-generalized-time) strings like this comes in handy.

So in your case, I would do

```
$CreatedDate = Get-ADUser -Identity $AcountName -Properties Created | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Created
```

Below a table that shows you the most commonly used attributes on users and how PowerShell maps them:

| Property | Syntax | R/RW | LDAPDisplayName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AccountLockoutTime | DateTime | RW | lockoutTime, converted to local time |
| AccountNotDelegated | Boolean | RW | userAccountControl (bit mask 1048576) |
| AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption | Boolean | RW | userAccountControl (bit mask 128) |
| BadLogonCount | Int32 | R | badPwdCount |
| CannotChangePassword | Boolean | RW | nTSecurityDescriptor |
| CanonicalName | String | R | canonicalName |
| Certificates | ADCollection | RW | userCertificate |
| ChangePasswordAtLogon | Boolean | W | If pwdLastSet = 0 |
| City | String | RW | l |
| CN | String | R | cn |
| Company | String | RW | company |
| Country | String | RW | c (2 character abbreviation) |
| Created | DateTime | R | whenCreated |
| Deleted | Boolean | R | isDeleted |
| Department | String | RW | department |
| Description | String | RW | description |
| DisplayName | String | RW | displayName |
| DistinguishedName | String (DN) | R | distinguishedName |
| Division | String | RW | division |
| DoesNotRequirePreAuth | Boolean | RW | userAccountControl (bit mask 4194304) |
| EmailAddress | String | RW | mail |
| EmployeeID | String | RW | employeeID |
| EmployeeNumber | String | RW | employeeNumber |
| Enabled | Boolean | RW | userAccountControl (bit mask not 2) |
| Fax | String | RW | facsimileTelephoneNumber |
| GivenName | String | RW | givenName |
| HomeDirectory | String | RW | homeDirectory |
| HomedirRequired | Boolean | RW | userAccountControl (bit mask 8) |
| HomeDrive | String | RW | homeDrive |
| HomePage | String | RW | wWWHomePage |
| HomePhone | String | RW | homePhone |
| Initials | String | RW | initials |
| LastBadPasswordAttempt | DateTime | R | badPasswordTime, converted to local time |
| LastKnownParent | String (DN) | R | lastKnownParent |
| LastLogonDate | DateTime | R | lastLogonTimeStamp, converted to local time |
| LockedOut | Boolean | RW | msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed (bit mask 16) |
| LogonWorkstations | String | RW | userWorkstations |
| Manager | String (DN) | RW | manager |
| MemberOf | ADCollection | R | memberOf |
| MNSLogonAccount | Boolean | RW | userAccountControl (bit mask 131072) |
| MobilePhone | String | RW | mobile |
| Modified | DateTime | R | whenChanged |
| Name | String | R | cn (Relative Distinguished Name) |
| ObjectCategory | String | R | objectCategory |
| ObjectClass | String | R | objectClass, most specific value |
| ObjectGUID | Guid | R | objectGUID converted to string |
| Office | String | RW | physicalDeliveryOfficeName |
| OfficePhone | String | RW | telephoneNumber |
| Organization | String | RW | o |
| OtherName | String | RW | middleName |
| PasswordExpired | Boolean | RW | msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed (bit mask 8388608) (see Note 1) |
| PasswordLastSet | DateTime | RW | pwdLastSet, local time |
| PasswordNeverExpires | Boolean | RW | userAccountControl (bit mask 65536) |
| PasswordNotRequired | Boolean | RW | userAccountControl (bit mask 32) |
| POBox | String | RW | postOfficeBox |
| PostalCode | String | RW | postalCode |
| PrimaryGroup | String | R | Group with primaryGroupToken |
| ProfilePath | String | RW | profilePath |
| ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion | Boolean | RW | nTSecurityDescriptor |
| SamAccountName | String | RW | sAMAccountName |
| ScriptPath | String | RW | scriptPath |
| ServicePrincipalNames | ADCollection | RW | servicePrincipalName |
| SID | Sid | R | objectSID converted to string |
| SIDHistory | ADCollection | R | sIDHistory |
| SmartcardLogonRequired | Boolean | RW | userAccountControl (bit mask 262144) |
| State | String | RW | st |
| StreetAddress | String | RW | streetAddress |
| Surname | String | RW | sn |
| Title | String | RW | title |
| TrustedForDelegation | Boolean | RW | userAccountControl (bit mask 524288) |
| TrustedToAuthForDelegation | Boolean | RW | userAccountControl (bit mask 16777216) |
| UseDESKeyOnly | Boolean | RW | userAccountControl (bit mask 2097152) |
| UserPrincipalName | String | RW | userPrincipalName |

Get-ADUser by default returns objects with these properties:
`DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName`. If you want more, then you need to specify the extra's with the `-Properties` parameter. Best **not** use `-Properties *`